# How can I animate a circle with PlayN?

Tags: playn

This is a follow up to my last question:

[How can I draw a circle to the screen with PlayN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478065/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-to-the-screen-with-playn)

For my simple case, I want to programmatically create a single colored circle and move it across a 2-D plain (doesn't need to use box2d lib).

A real-world example would likely involve animating several circles. Two real-world examples for this case (*sorry, I had to remove the links -- not enough karma!*):

- Browsmos for Chrome
- Ants AI Challenge

It was suggested in response to my last question that I would want to use the [ImmediateLayer class](http://code.google.com/p/playn/source/browse/tests/core/src/playn/tests/core/ImmediateTest.java), so I am looking to understand how to properly incorporate this into my game loop.

Here's is my code sample:

```
public class SimpleCircleAnimation implements Game {

    // Surface    
    private GroupLayer rootLayer;
    private ImmediateLayer surface;
    private Canvas canvas;

    private Circle circle;
    private CanvasImage circleImage;        

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // create root layer
        rootLayer = graphics().rootLayer();

        // a simple circle object
        int circleX = 0; int circleY = 0;
        int circleRadius = 20;
        circle = new Circle(circleX, circleY, circleRadius);

        // create an immediate layer and add to root layer
        ImmediateLayer circleLayer = graphics().createImmediateLayer(new ImmediateLayer.Renderer() {
            public void render (Surface surf) {
                circleImage = graphics().createImage(circle.radius*2,  circle.radius*2);
                canvas = circleImage.canvas();
                canvas.setFillColor(0xff0000eb);
                canvas.fillCircle(circle.radius, circle.radius, circle.radius);
                surf.drawImage(circleImage, circle.x, circle.y);
            }
        });
        rootLayer.add(circleLayer);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(float alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float delta) {
        // move circle
        int newX = circle.x + 4; int newY = circle.y + 4;
        circle.setPoint(newX, newY);
    }

    @Override
    public int updateRate() {
        return 25;
    }
}
```

This successfully moves the circle diagonally down the screen from left to right. A couple questions:

- Is this implemented properly?
- In the case of multiple animated circles, is the idea with ImmediateLayer that you would create a circle image for each circle within the Renderer callback? Or would you perhaps create an Immediate Layer for each circle and add those to the root layer?

Comment: Let's see if I can add the example links here: [Browsmos](http://html5games.com/2011/06/browsmos/), [Ant AI Challenge](http://aichallenge.org/visualizer.php?game=346330)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a detailed practical example of ImmediateLayer usage in the Cute Game source within the PlayN Samples:

[CuteGame.java (code.google.com)](http://code.google.com/p/playn-samples/source/browse/cute/core/src/main/java/playn/sample/cute/core/CuteGame.java#127)

Answer (score 0):

I would not use ImmediateLayer wiht render (Surface surf) adapter. Here u have, inside the render method creation of an image

```
circleImage = graphics().createImage(circle.radius*2,  circle.radius*2);
```

---

just put this in the paint method

```
surf.drawImage(circleImage, circle.x, circle.y);
```

using the normal layer and u should be fine

Painting is done in paint method, and do not put calculations there
Update is for calculations, and physics oriented stuff

Comment: Thanks for the response. This advice contradicts that given by @samskivert here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9486105/1093087. For the case I describe, he suggests that using ImmediateLayer will get better performance.

Comment: than hear the answer from samskivert... i do not know what is ur exact implementation, but if he says  it should be immediate he is most probably right

Comment: My specific case was creating images programmatically (draw a circle, move it around) rather than animating loaded image files/sprites. However, CuteGame is using loaded images with ImmediateLayer, so I'm not quite sure what the argument is against using ImmediateLayer.